# Integrating one app with other in iOS

Tags: ios, url

I have two applications A and B, now i want to pass a PDF from A app to B app. If the B app is not installed then i want to notify users to download it. If it's installed then the B app should get the document. I tried with custom url scheme but not able to transfer file.

My approach is:

[image]

Comment: Show how you tried with a custom URL scheme (that is the correct approach).

Comment: Please post formatted code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can get inspiration from Facebook SDK for iOS. They allow SSO from appliction A to Facebook Application.

Comment: I am not going to copy/paste here  all the Facebook SDK documentation (since it changes everytime), you can go on facebook dev site end read the doc.

Comment: I am using this code -(IBAction) openReceiverApp:(id)sender {
    // Opens the Receiver app if installed, otherwise displays an error
    UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSString *URLEncodedText = [self.textBox.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *ourPath = [@"readtext://" stringByAppendingString:URLEncodedText];
    NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
    if ([ourApplication canOpenURL:ourURL]) {
        [ourApplication openURL:ourURL];
    }
   
}

Comment: Simply, i want to do open link shown in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUgASgjAK3E watch from 20th second. It opens other app with the document.